# how to prevent duplicates string in array and

Tags: java, arrays

```
package jellyProblem;
import java.util.*;

public class jellyProblem   {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int studentNumbers = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        String [] name =new String [100];
        int [] volume=new int[100];

        while(true){
            if (studentNumbers==0)
                break ;
            else
            for(int i=0;i<studentNumbers;i++){
                name[i]=input.next();
                int length =input.nextInt();
                int width =input.nextInt();
                int height =input.nextInt();

                System.out.printf("\n%s %d %d %d\n",name[i],length,width,height);     
                volume[i]=length*height*width;                      
            }
            int minimum=0,maximum=0;
            for(int i=1;i<studentNumbers;++i){
                if (volume[i]<volume[minimum])
                    minimum=i;
                if (volume[i]>volume[maximum])
                    maximum=i;
            }
            if(volume[minimum]==volume[maximum])
                System.out.println("\nno child lost his jelly\n");
            else
                System.out.printf("\n%s has lost jelly to %s.\n",name[minimum],name[maximum]);
            studentNumbers = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
        }

    }
}
```

First request I don't know how to:

1. Prevent string duplicates in `names[]` array like
2. I want to stop array  if characters of `name[]` is more than past (`names[i].length<=10`) it doesn't work with me

Comment: can you provide input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int studentNumbers = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    int[] volume = new int[100];
    // clear all data to make it clean
    names.clear();
    while (true) {

        if (studentNumbers == 0)
            break;
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < studentNumbers; i++) {
                String studentName = input.next();
                // here is how prevent string duplicates in names[] array like
                if (names.contains(studentName)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (studentName.length() > 10) {
                    break;
                }
                names.add(studentName);
                int length = input.nextInt();
                int width = input.nextInt();
                int height = input.nextInt();

                System.out.printf("\n%s %d %d %d\n", names.get(i), length, width, height);
                volume[i] = length * height * width;
            }
        int minimum = 0, maximum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < studentNumbers; ++i) {
            if (volume[i] < volume[minimum])
                minimum = i;
            if (volume[i] > volume[maximum])
                maximum = i;
        }
        if (volume[minimum] == volume[maximum])
            System.out.println("\nno child lost his jelly\n");
        else
            System.out.printf("\n%s has lost jelly to %s.\n", names.get(minimum), names.get(maximum));
        studentNumbers = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

a. Instead of using an Array of string you can use an ArrayList. The ArrayList will give you the power to perform various function over the list of String. Incase you want to write your own method and only allow non duplicates to be inserted into the Array then u can iterate over the array and check whether you encounter the same value. eg.

```
String newName =  input.nextLine(); 
boolean checkDuplicate = dupliacteFunction(newName,name);

boolean dupliacteFunction(String newName , String []nameArray) {
for(String nameValue : nameArray) {
if(newName .equals(nameValue)) 
    return true;
}
else return false;
}
```

b.  String newName =  input.nextLine(); 
    newName.length();// This will give u the size of the string being read.

Please try and implement these changes and then we can suggest further alternatives. Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, there is no real way to prevent duplicates in an array. I would use an ArrayList object. If it is absolutely impossible to use an ArrayList, you could create a method like this:

```
public static String[] removeDupes(String[] array){
        ArrayList<String> uniqueItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String s : array){
            if(uniqueItems.contains(s) == false)
                uniqueItems.add(s);
        }
        array = uniqueItems.toArray(array);
        return array;
    }
```

And to answer your second question, I don't know what you mean by "stop array" but it seems like all you need is a simple if-statement with exactly the condition you described.